# How to build drupal-twitter bot like the one on drupal.org

Tags: 7

I'm really impressed by this bot:  [drupal8changes](https://twitter.com/drupal8changes) which gets changes from http://drupal.org/list-changes/drupal and posts it on to Twitter. I think it might be something like, when a new node is created of D8Changes content-type, then post it on to twitter. Isn't it awesome? I want to know how that could be implemented? Not just limited to twitter, but for Facebook, Google+ etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using [Twitter](https://drupal.org/project/twitter) & [Oauth](https://drupal.org/project/oauth) module. You will have to create a twitter app & use Consumer key, Consumer secret to connect to your twitter account.

You will have to choose a content type for tweet & yeah don't forget to enabled import option on twitter account.